# C++ WinSock Bluetooth Connection - AT Command - Error Received

Tags: android, c++, windows, bluetooth

This is a continuation of this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020491/programming-for-bluetooth-in-winsock-a-solution-needed

I am not strong in C++!

The Lib/Header files can be found here C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um which is part of the Windows SDK Kit here: [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk) or here [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

My Code:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 
// MSDN Bluetooth and read or write operations:
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362907(v=vs.85).aspx
// 
// MSDN Bluetooth and Connect
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362901(v=vs.85).aspx
//
// MSDN Send Function
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx
// 
// Error Codes: 
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx
// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Includes:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <bthsdpdef.h>
#include <bluetoothapis.h>

#include <ws2bth.h>

// Preprocessor Directive: Pragma's:
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


// define Directive's:
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

DEFINE_GUID(GUID_NULL, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");


int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{


std::cout << "******************************************************\r\n";

//--------------------------------------------
// Locals:
//--------------------------------------------
int result = 0;
ULONG iResult = 0;
LPTSTR RemoteEndPointMACAddr = (LPTSTR)"38:2D:E8:B9:FA:EB";


//--------------------------------------------
// Prep the Buffer's:
//--------------------------------------------
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
char *sendbuf = "AT+COPS?\r";


//--------------------------------------------
// Initialise WinSock.
//--------------------------------------------
WSADATA WSAData = { 0 };
WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
if ((iResult = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &WSAData)) != 0)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'WSAData' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// The WinSock Socket.
//--------------------------------------------
SOCKET LocalSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;


//--------------------------------------------
// Local End Point SOCKADDR_BTH.
//--------------------------------------------
SOCKADDR_BTH LocalEndpoint;
// number of service channel, 0 or BT_PORT_ANY;
LocalEndpoint.port = 0;
LocalEndpoint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
LocalEndpoint.btAddr = 0;
LocalEndpoint.serviceClassId = GUID_NULL;
std::cout << "  Local EndPoint Address: " << LocalEndpoint.btAddr << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Remote End Point SOCKADDR_BTH.
//--------------------------------------------
SOCKADDR_BTH RemoteEndPoint;
// number of service channel, 0 or BT_PORT_ANY;
RemoteEndPoint.port = 0;
RemoteEndPoint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
RemoteEndPoint.btAddr = BTH_ADDR(0x382DE8B9FAEB);
RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
int BTHAddrLength = sizeof(RemoteEndPoint);
std::cout << "  Remote EndPoint Address: " << RemoteEndPoint.btAddr << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Create the socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((LocalSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'socket' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Bind the socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = bind(LocalSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&LocalEndpoint, sizeof(LocalEndpoint))) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'bind' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Connect the socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = connect(LocalSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&RemoteEndPoint, sizeof(RemoteEndPoint))) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'connect' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Send the Buffer.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = send(LocalSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'send' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";
std::cout << "  Bytes Sent: " << sendbuf << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Receive until the peer termination.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = recv(LocalSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0)) >= 1)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'recv' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";
std::cout << "  Data Received: " << recvbuf << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Shutdown the connection.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = shutdown(LocalSocket, SD_SEND)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'shutdown' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Close the Socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = closesocket(LocalSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'closesocket' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


WSACleanup();


std::cout << "END: " << "Application has completed!" << "\r\n";


std::getchar();


return 0;

}
```

Is someone able to tell me where I am going wrong, I am trying to send and receive AT Commands to the Bluetooth GSM Device. It’s a Samsung Ace.

I keep getting 'ERROR' returned. [The command returns "OK" ..., and "ERROR" otherwise](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/hayes-at-commands.html) - However all AT Commands Fail with 'ERROR'

I have tried several UUID GUID's.

My Output is like so:

```
******************************************************
WINSOCK: 'WSAData' Return Code: 0
        Local EndPoint Address: 0
        Remote EndPoint Address: 61769829186283
WINSOCK: 'socket' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'bind' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'connect' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'send' Return Code: 0
        Bytes Sent: AT+COPS?
WINSOCK: 'recv' Return Code: 0
        Data Received:
ERROR

WINSOCK: 'shutdown' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'closesocket' Return Code: 0
END: Application has completed!
```

At the very least, I hope my questions help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working!

For others out there, and there are many from my research, I hope this helps: If it has, please vote up!

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 
// MSDN Bluetooth and Connect
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362901(v=vs.85).aspx
//
// MSDN Send Function
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx
// 
// MSDN Bluetooth and read or write operations:
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362907(v=vs.85).aspx
// 
// Error Codes: 
// See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx
// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Includes:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <bthsdpdef.h>
#include <bluetoothapis.h>

#include <ws2bth.h>

// Preprocessor Directive: Pragma's:
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


// define Directive's:
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

DEFINE_GUID(GUID_NULL, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");


int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{


std::cout << "******************************************************\r\n";

//--------------------------------------------
// Locals:
//--------------------------------------------
int result = 0;
ULONG iResult = 0;
LPTSTR RemoteEndPointMACAddress = (LPTSTR)"38:2D:E8:B9:FA:EB";


//--------------------------------------------
// Prep the Buffer's:
//--------------------------------------------
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
char *sendbuf = "AT+COPS?\r";
int len = (int)strlen(sendbuf);


//--------------------------------------------
// Initialise WinSock.
//--------------------------------------------
WSADATA WSAData = { 0 };
WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
if ((iResult = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &WSAData)) != 0)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'WSAData' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// The WinSock Socket.
//--------------------------------------------
SOCKET LocalSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;


//--------------------------------------------
// Local End Point SOCKADDR_BTH.
//--------------------------------------------
SOCKADDR_BTH LocalEndpoint;
// number of service channel, 0 or BT_PORT_ANY;
LocalEndpoint.port = 0;
LocalEndpoint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
LocalEndpoint.btAddr = 0;
LocalEndpoint.serviceClassId = GUID_NULL;
std::cout << "   Local EndPoint Address: " << LocalEndpoint.btAddr << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Remote End Point SOCKADDR_BTH.
//--------------------------------------------
SOCKADDR_BTH RemoteEndPoint;
// number of service channel, 0 or BT_PORT_ANY;
RemoteEndPoint.port = 0;
RemoteEndPoint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
RemoteEndPoint.btAddr = BTH_ADDR(0x382DE8B9FAEB);
RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID; // RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID
int BTHAddrLength = sizeof(RemoteEndPoint);
std::cout << "   Remote EndPoint Address: " << RemoteEndPoint.btAddr << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Create the socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((LocalSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'socket' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Bind the socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = bind(LocalSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&LocalEndpoint, sizeof(LocalEndpoint))) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'bind' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Connect the socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = connect(LocalSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&RemoteEndPoint, sizeof(RemoteEndPoint))) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'connect' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Send the Buffer.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = send(LocalSocket, sendbuf, len, MSG_OOB)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'send' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";
std::cout << "   Bytes Sent: " << sendbuf << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Receive until the peer termination.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = recv(LocalSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'recv' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";
std::cout << "   Data Received: " << recvbuf << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Shutdown the connection.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = shutdown(LocalSocket, SD_SEND)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'shutdown' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


//--------------------------------------------
// Close the Socket.
//--------------------------------------------
if ((iResult = closesocket(LocalSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
}
std::cout << "WINSOCK: 'closesocket' Return Code: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\r\n";


WSACleanup();


std::cout << "END: " << "Application has completed!" << "\r\n";


std::getchar();


return 0;

}
```

I had to use the 'HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID' UUID as you can see. I also set the Stream Type to 'MSG_OOB' in the send Method.

My Output:

```
******************************************************
WINSOCK: 'WSAData' Return Code: 0
         Local EndPoint Address: 0
         Remote EndPoint Address: 61769829186283
WINSOCK: 'socket' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'bind' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'connect' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'send' Return Code: 0
         Bytes Sent: AT+COPS?
WINSOCK: 'recv' Return Code: 0
         Data Received:
+COPS: 0,0,"My Provider"

WINSOCK: 'shutdown' Return Code: 0
WINSOCK: 'closesocket' Return Code: 0
END: Application has completed!
```

**EDIT**
If you want to send SMS Messages, a Server Socket will be needed on the GSM Device: [Xamarin Android Connecting with bluetooth device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL_CQmmsKSQ)
or: [Android Bluetooth COM port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565144/android-bluetooth-com-port) or [SENA BTerm Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sena.bterm)